# Unit tests in systems programming?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I would like to start learning/using unit tests in C++. However, I'm having a hard time applying the concept of tests to my field of programming.

I'm usually not writing functions which follow a predefined input/output pattern, instead, my programming is usually on a level rather close to the operating system.

Some examples are: find out Windows version, create a system restore point, query registry for installed drives, compress a file, or recursively find all .log files older than X days.

I don't see how I could hard-code "results" into a testing function. Are unit tests even possible in my case?

Comment: Your calls are not 'close to the operating system'.  Instead, you are making calls to the OS, which is normal for nearly anything you write in a language like c++. For example, if your test inserts a value into the registry and then verifies that your retrieval function does indeed return that value, you've written a unit test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "result" doesn't have to be a CONSTANT value, it could be something that the code finds out. For example, if you are compressing a file, the result would be a file that, when uncompressed, gives you the original file. So the test would be to take an existing test-file , compress it, and then uncompress the resulting compressed file, then compare the two files. If the result is "no difference", it's a pass. If the files are not the same, you have a problem of some sort.

The same principle can be applied to any of your other methods. Finding log-files would of course require that you prepare a number of files, and given them different times (using the [`SetFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or some such).

Getting Windows version should give you the version of the Windows you are currently using.

And so on.

Of course, you should also have "negative" tests whenever possible. If you are compressing a file, what happens if you try to compress a file that doesn't exist? What if the disk is full (using a virtual harddisk or similar can help here, as filling your entire disk may not result in something great!). If the specification says the code should behave in a certain way, then verify that it gives the correct error message. Otherwise, at least ensure it doesn't "crash", or fail without an error message of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have some mocking objects which will fake the OS calls:

You may have a class OS which have methods which mimics the system calls.
So your algorithm don't call directly the global os function.

then you can construct a fake OS class which returns some sort of "hard coded" values for the testing.